# Vue dynamic xlink:href attr

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to pass icon name as props to a vue component and use it to render icon depends on that icon name.
I did it by passing icon name to component and bind xlink:href to a data property call href but it does not work! :/
How can i do that?
Here is component code:

```
<template>
  <svg class="icon">
      <use :xlink:href="href"></use>
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Icon',
  props: {
    icon: String
  },
  data: function () {
      return {
        href: `@sprite#icon-kb-${this.icon}`
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

and here is the component usage code:

```
<Icon icon="down"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure about `@sprite#icon-kb-down${this.icon}` ?

Comment: @MichalLevý yeah bro i am sure about this

Comment: really ? icon is `@sprite#icon-kb-downdown` ?

Comment: @MichalLevý thanks, I fix it but it is not really important here...

Comment: OK, so what "does not work" exactly means? It is not rendering at all, is it rendering but inccorrectly or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it works just fine...

```js
const icon = Vue.component('Icon', {
  props: {
    icon: String
  },
  data: function () {
      return {
        href: `#${this.icon}`
      }
    },
  template: `
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <use :xlink:href="href"></use>
  </svg>
  `
})

const ap = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { icon },
  data() {
    return {
      icons: ['icon-8pt-star', 'icon-star']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    iconsInReverseOrder() {
      return this.icons.slice().reverse()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Icon v-for="(icon, index) in icons" :icon="icon" :key="icon+'1'"></Icon>
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="icon-8pt-star" viewBox="0 0 95 95">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M83.59,63.91,97.5,50,83.59,36.09V16.41H63.91L50,2.5,36.09,16.41H16.41V36.09L2.5,50,16.41,63.91V83.59H36.09L50,97.5,63.91,83.59H83.59Z" transform="translate(-2.5 -2.5)"/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="icon-star" viewBox="0 0 95 95">
    <polygon points="47.5 0 62.18 31.27 95 36.29 71.25 60.63 76.86 95 47.5 78.77 18.14 95 23.75 60.63 0 36.29 32.82 31.27 47.5 0"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```