# Unable to embed SVG symbol with vue 2.6.11

Tags: vuejs2

I can't bind xlink:href in <use> object inside my SVG:

```
// The example below works fine:
<use xlink:href="../assets/test.svg#block1"/> // <- OK

// The examples below doesn't embed an element
<use :href="'../assets/test.svg#block1'"/> // <- NOK
<use :xlink:href="'../assets/test.svg#block1'"/> // <- NOK
<use v-bind:xlink:href="'../assets/test.svg#block1'"/> // <- NOK
<use v-bind="{ 'xlink:href': '../assets/test.svg#block1' }"/> // <- NOK
```

**"vue": "^2.6.11"**

Does anybody know if I'm wrong with syntax, or it is a bug in current version?

Comment: maybe because you left out the `xlink:` part ?

Comment: Nope, I've tried several methods, according to official api -> https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64305134/381282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was quite easy: require SVG file and then add #id of needed symbol:

```
<use :xlink:href="require('@/assets/test.svg') + `#${block_name}` />
```